# Slow byte[] to String constructor

Tags: java, android, string, constructor

I'm writing android java application (minSdkVersion 15) to get university timetable from php-site through api in json format. After decompressing content with InflaterInputStream i got a byte array in UTF-8 encoding and want to convert it to string to map to objects via Jackson/GSON or some other library.
Unfortunatelly constructing string from a little more than 4.000.000 bytes long array takes about 10 minutes.

```
String result = new String(resultArray, "UTF-8");
```

I found this article (http://java-performance.info/inefficient-byte-to-string-constructor/)
which probably have some solution to this problem but can't understand it.
May be there is some better way of such conversion?

Comment: It might be better to wrap the stream and use one of the methods that each of those libraries has for decoding JSON from streams or readers instead of `String`s.

Comment: Try to save received result in file, and then read string from file line by line.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the main point of the article is that Java 6 has a 'broken' implementation of that constructor, and that the problem goes away on newer versions of Java.

For instance, I wrote a quick test program that generates 4M random bytes and converts the resulting array into a string using the same constructor, but with Java 8, and it's quite snappy:

```
    byte[] arr = new byte[4000000];
    Random r = new Random();
    r.nextBytes(arr);

    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    String result = new String(arr, "UTF-8");
    System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() - start); // takes ~100 ms
```

Comment: While on my slower machine i got around 200 ms on this, that wasn't the part i don't understand.
I think there is some optimization fix for Java 6 (something similar i guess is in android implementation). Probably making temporary copy of array is needed ("Copy required part of byte[] to temporary array before calling this constructor") but i can't get this to perform much better than original one line solution.

Answer (score 0):

We have a similar problem with android. 
we are not that slow, but the new String(byte[], "UTF-8") is showing up as our main performance problem.

[image]

The new String(byte[]) is calling StringFactory.newStringFromBytes() and as you can see that is the slowest method in the list.

by looking at the code, you can see that there is a "TODO: Implement this method natively". 
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/+/master/libart/src/main/java/java/lang/StringFactory.java#77